# How to open outlook mailbox from application menu?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I redirect user to outlook mailbox from application `navbar` and I want to add mail to address e.g mailto@gmail.com.

I have tried below `mailto` it opens up outlook and To address , its throwing below error.

How can I achieve that task using angularJs ?

navigation.html

```
<a ng-href="mailto:{{mailto:john@gmail.com}}">Help</a>
```

Error:

> angular-ui-router.js:3839 Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 12-12 [@] in expression [mailto:JOHN@GMAIL.COM].

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me. Thanks

```
<a href="mailto:JOHN@GMAIL.COM">Help</a>
```